# Show that $A[X,Y]/(X-Y)\cong A[X]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Show that $$A[X,Y]/(X-Y)\cong A[X].$$

My idea was to defined 
\begin{align*}
\Phi: A[X,Y]&\longrightarrow A[X]\\
P(X,Y)&\longmapsto P(X,0).
\end{align*}

The surjectivity is obvious. Now, $$\Phi(P(X,Y))=0\iff P(X,0)=0\iff Y\mid P(X,0)\iff P(X,Y)\in (Y).$$
Unfortunatly, I get that $$A[X,Y]/(Y)\cong A[X].$$
Is it true ? How can I show that $$A[X,Y]/(X-Y)\cong A[X]\ \ ?$$

Comment: Have you tried $P(X,Y)\mapsto P(X,X)$?

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba: Brilliant !! Beautiful, thanks. By the way, does my proof show that $A[X,Y]/(Y)\cong A[X]$ ? By the way, you should put your comment as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks! By the way, your proof (of $A[X,Y]/(Y)\cong A[X]$) looks okay to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show that $A[X,Y]/(X-Y)\cong A[X]$ with the surjection $\varphi\colon A[X,Y]\to A[X]$ defined as $\varphi(P(X,Y))=P(X,X)$.

The intuition behind this is that in $A[X,Y]/(X-Y)$, we have $\overline{X}=\overline{Y}$, so it is natural to ask that $\varphi$ doesn't distinguish between them.

**EDIT**: In general, for a commutative ring $R$ and polynomials $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ such that the leading coeficient of $g$ is an unit of $R$, there are exist uniques $q(x),r(x)\in R[x]$ such that $$f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x),$$ with $\deg{r(x)}<\deg{g(x)}$. A proof for this result is given [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&lpg=PP1&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA173#v=onepage&q&f=false).

In your case, we may take $R=A[X]$, $f=P(X,Y)$ and $g=X-Y$, which gives $Q(X,Y),S(X,Y)\in A[X,Y]$ such that
$$P(X,Y)=Q(X,Y)\cdot (X-Y)+S(X,Y),$$
such that the degree of $S(X,Y)$ is less than $1$ (in the indeterminate $Y$), meaning that $S(X,Y)$ is in fact a member of $A[X]$, say $S(X)$. But now,
$$0=P(X,X)=Q(X,X)(X-X)+S(X)= S(X)\Rightarrow P(X,Y)=Q(X,Y)\cdot (X-Y).$$

Comment: Just a last small thing, I finally don't see why $$P(X,X)=0\iff (X-Y)\mid P(X,Y)\ \ ?$$

Comment: @user330587 I edited my answer.

Comment: magnificent !! thank you :)

Comment: Then $X-a$ divide $f(X)$, but how can it be adapted to the problem ? @Surb

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write $R[Y]$ (and not $\mathbb R[X]$). Therefore, if $R=A[X]$, since in $R[Y]$, $P(X,X)=0$, you get that $Y=X$ is a root, and thus $Y-X$ divide $P(X,Y)$.

Comment: @user330587 Surb is absolutely right. Let me know if something is not clear yet.